# How can set full screen background gif in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fullscreen

I have a GIF image in my app and want this to become my full screen background. I use width and height = match parent but it's not becoming full screen. Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
    GifView pGif = (GifView) findViewById(R.id.gif);
    pGif.setImageResource(R.drawable.bbbb);
}}
```

and this is my class:

```
public class GifView extends View {


    private static final int DEFAULT_MOVIEW_DURATION = 1000;

    private int mMovieResourceId;
    private Movie mMovie;

    private long mMovieStart = 0;
    private int mCurrentAnimationTime = 0;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        /**
         * Starting from HONEYCOMB have to turn off HardWare acceleration to draw
         * Movie on Canvas.
         */
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
    }

    public void setImageResource(int mvId){
        this.mMovieResourceId = mvId;
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(mMovieResourceId));
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if(mMovie != null){
            setMeasuredDimension(mMovie.width(), mMovie.height());
        }else{
            setMeasuredDimension(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mMovie != null){
            updateAnimtionTime();
            drawGif(canvas);
            invalidate();
        }else{
            drawGif(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void updateAnimtionTime() {
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        if (mMovieStart == 0) {
            mMovieStart = now;
        }
        int dur = mMovie.duration();
        if (dur == 0) {
            dur = DEFAULT_MOVIEW_DURATION;
        }
        mCurrentAnimationTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
    }

    private void drawGif(Canvas canvas) {
        mMovie.setTime(mCurrentAnimationTime);
        mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
        canvas.restore();
    }

}
```

and xml :

```
<com.example.fabulous.comic.GifView
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/gif"/>
```

Comment: Please post your xml code also !

Comment: for full screen you have need different resolution GIF images for it because GifVIew has not method for fixXY like imageview

Comment: Also be careful with the imagesize! If the size is too big, the activity may crash. Consider using **BitmapFactory** or something equal for Compressing the image

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with help of [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

It is an image loading and caching library for Android focused on smooth scrolling

Glide supports fetching, decoding, and displaying video stills, images, and animated GIFs

you can use Glide using this

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relative"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <!--Rest of your coding-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

java

```
ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

Glide.with(Gif.this).load(R.drawable.giphy).asGif().into(img);
```

ps: i do not tested the code

Answer (score 0):

Try using **WebView**, layout your view using simple **html** with your background as the gif then put it on your assets directory and load it using **WebView**. I have tried this on my other project, probably not the best solution but it works and quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

In file build.gradle(module) add dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

For a simple view:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  Glide.with(this).load("*link to image*").into(imageView);
}
```

Set in all layouts around image:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```